# adding subView to the UINavigationBar and removing it

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, subview

I am trying to create a custom look of my UINavigationBar. When the user puts the app in landscape, the navigationBar should be covered with an Image. When rotated back to portrait I want the View(Image) removed. Everything works fine with the code below except removing it. I can remove the View if I put the code in the same if-statement, but nothing happens if I put it in the else if-statement. Have I missed something ?  / Regards

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

    UIView *v =  [[UIView alloc]init];

     if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{

    v.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,44);
    v.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar25g.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    //[v removeFromSuperview]; <----- works if I put it here

     NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE");//load the landscape view

}
     else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
           [v removeFromSuperview]; <----- Not working


         NSLog(@"PORTRAIT"); //load the portrait view

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason that you cannot remove it is every time you go into the method you create a new instance of the UIView *v.

Create an instance variable then assign the view to that. Once it is assigned you can then remove or add as needed.

If you do not want to use an instance variable then you can give the view a tag i.e.

```
UIView *v = nil;

v = [self.view viewForTag:1000];

if (!v) {
    v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v.tag = 1000;
    v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 44);
    v.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar25g.png"]];
}
```

Now you can do your adding and removing for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UIAppearance?

```
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```